# Lie bracket and Ricci tensor

Tags: lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry, curvature

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891780/whether-ricci-flow-keep-the-diagonal-of-metric-and-ricci-tensor) , I don't know why the Lie bracket is needed to compute Ricci tensor. In my view , knowing the metric is enough to compute Ricci tensor.But if just using metric ,I can't get the same result of THW. I am not familiar with Lie algrebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One explanation comes from using the Koszul Formula to the calculate the connection.

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.  Recall that the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ is defined uniquely by requiring that
\begin{align*}
2 g\left(\nabla_{X}Y, Z\right) = &X\cdot g(Y, Z) + Y\cdot g(Z, X) - Z\cdot g(X, Y)\\
&g(\left[X, Y\right], Z) - g([X, Z], Y) - g([Y, Z], X) 
\end{align*}
for all vector fields $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ on $M$.  Note that the notation of $\cdot$ is used to indicate the directional derivative of the scalar function determined by $g(-, -)$ restricted to two vector fields in the indicated direction.

One can then compute the connection coefficients (or Christoffel symbols) relative to a given frame $E_{1}, E_{2}, \ldots, E_{n}$ by writing $\nabla_{E_{i}}E_{j} = \Gamma_{ij}^{k}E_{k}$ and then substituting into the Koszul formula and solving for $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}$.

Computing the connection coefficients in this way is simplified greatly in two particular instances.

1. The chosen frame $E_{1}, E_{2}, \ldots, E_{n}$ is a local-coordinate frame, in which case the Lie brackets all vanish.
2. $(M)$ is a Lie group and $g$ is a left invariant metric.  In this instance, one can select the frame $E_{1}, E_{2}, \ldots , E_{n}$ to be a left invariant frame so that both $g$ and the frame are determined at the identity of $G$, i.e., at the Lie algebra of $G$.  In this instance, the expressions $g(E_i, E_j)$ are constant, so the directional derivatives in the first line on the right hand side of the Koszul formula are all zero.  When restricted to basis/frame vectors, the second line of the Koszul formula then reduces to an expression involving the $g_{ij}$ of the metric and the structure constants of the Lie algebra.  The connection coefficients $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}$ will then depend solely on those two sets of quantities.  Note that this can be further simplified by requiring that the left invariant frame is an orthonormal frame for $g$.

It should also be noted that there are other ways to compute the Ricci curvature in the setting of a Lie group.